# HTTP POST request failed with response as null values in angular 2 using typescript

Tags: angular, http-post, typescript2.0

I am working on Angular 2 technology, in one of my current project I was faced the issue in HTTTP POST request using typescript code.

This is the code I wrote in **myservice.ts**

```
 postVehicleInfoRestful(vehicleInfo: VehicleInfoTable): Observable<VehicleInfoTable> {

    console.log('VehicleInfo Service.')

    //let body = JSON.stringify(vehicleInfo ? vehicleInfo  : null);
    let body = JSON.stringify(vehicleInfo);
    console.log(body);

    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }); //'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' application/json


    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });//, method: "post"

    console.log(this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl + '/api/VehicleInfoTable');

    return this._http.post(this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl + '/api/VehicleInfoTable', body, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And also, wrote the code in **mycomponenet.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log(' VehicleInfoComponent In OnInit');

    this.vehicleInfo.ID = 7;
    this.vehicleInfo.AssetType = 'Auto';
    this.vehicleInfo.IntendedUse = 'Personal';
    this.vehicleInfo.NeworUsed = 'New';
    this.vehicleInfo.SSN = '123456789';
    this.vehicleInfo.VehicleYear = '1';
    this.vehicleInfo.VehicleMake = '2';
    this.vehicleInfo.VehicleModel = '3';
    this.vehicleInfo.VIN = 'US123';
    this.vehicleInfo.CurrentMileage = '40';             
}

 saveVehicleInfo() {

    console.log('Save Vehicle Info Details.');
    console.log(this.vehicleInfo);

    this._vehicleInfoService.postVehicleInfoRestful(this.vehicleInfo).subscribe(//call the post
        data => this.postVehicleInfoToServer = JSON.stringify(data),// put the data returned from the server in our variable
        error => console.log("Error HTTP Post Service"),// in case of failure show this message
        () => console.log("Job Done Post !"));  //run this code in all cases   

}
```

This is the code I wrote in **mycontroller.cs**

```
 public async Task Post(VehicleInfoTable vehicleInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            //owner = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

            using (var client = NewDataAPIClient())
            {
                await client.VehicleInfoTables.PostVehicleInfoTableByVehicleinfotableAsync(new VehicleInfoTable
                {

                    ID = (int)vehicleInfo.ID,
                    AssetType = vehicleInfo.AssetType,
                    IntendedUse = vehicleInfo.IntendedUse,
                    NeworUsed = vehicleInfo.NeworUsed,
                    SSN = vehicleInfo.SSN,
                    VehicleYear = vehicleInfo.VehicleYear,
                    VehicleMake = vehicleInfo.VehicleMake,
                    VehicleModel = vehicleInfo.VehicleModel,
                    VIN = vehicleInfo.VIN,
                    CurrentMileage = vehicleInfo.CurrentMileage
                });
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("VehicleInfoTableController in ToDoListAPI");
            DevInsights.TrackEvent("VehicleInfoTableController in ToDoListAPI", "Post");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DevInsights.TrackException(ex, "VehicleInfoTableController in ToDoListAPI", "Post");
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

when I debug my code, once click on save button, based on my post url this method will fired **public async Task Post(VehicleInfoTable vehicleInfo)
        {
......
}**
but in that **vehicleInfo** parameter contains all fields value will be **null** but when I make post request I added the data in the body.

Can you please tell me where I did mistake for adding the data to body in http post request.

[image]

Can you please tell me where I did mistake and how can I resolve this issue?

-Pradeep

Comment: When the post request fails, what is the error you receive?

Comment: Thanks, can you please see my updated question once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT I could suggest two options for you to try, either:

Try this, make it as simple as possible first, then try to add more moving parts ;)

```
postVehicleInfoRestful(vehicleInfo: VehicleInfoTable) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(vehicleInfo);
    let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); 
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl + '/api/VehicleInfoTable', body, options)
      .map((res: Response) => { console.log('res', res); }) // let's see what we get
}
```

or:

```
postVehicleInfoRestful(vehicleInfo: VehicleInfoTable) {
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    // mark all your properties and values below with body.set
    body.set('yourPropertyName1', vehicleInfo.property1)
    body.set('yourPropertyName2', vehicleInfo.property2)
    let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}); 
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(this._settingsService.todoListAPIUrl + '/api/VehicleInfoTable', body.toString(), options)
      .map((res: Response) => { console.log('res', res); }) // let's see what we get
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code with above lines but it won't works ,it gives exception like "OPTIONS http://localhost:46439/api/VehicleInfoTable 405 (Method Not Allowed)", XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:46439/api/VehicleInfoTable. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.

Comment: Updated my answer, try the second one... no idea if that would work, but you can try :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `map(res => console.log(res.json()))` on the Observable in `myservice.ts` is mapping the result to type `void`. Correct to `map(res => res.json())` instead. The RXJS Observable `do(...)` method is designed exactly for this purpose, as it does not affect the Observable's contents.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code with what you said above, but still also facing the same issue as it's return null value.

Comment: Did you inspect the server's response externally to ensure the response's body content is not null?

Comment: Thanks , can you please see my updated question once.

Comment: I doubt this error is on the Angular side. If you have corrected the `map(...)` issue then Angular will simply return the HTTP post response body as an object. Since there is no error, it is most likely that your controller is returning an empty response body.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the map(....) issue but once post request fired my controller method in that vehicleinfo contains null value. I don't know how it be null even I supplied the data in http post request.